# Chart.js remove shadow from line chart

Tags: charts, chart.js, line, shadow

can anyone tell me how can I remove the shadow behind the line chart as in the image below?

[Image with the shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T1ax.png)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Setting the line configuration in global options.

```
var options = {
  elements: {
    line: {
      tension: 0
    }
  }
};
```

2. Setting `lineTension` to 0 in datasets.

```
var chartData = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: "Chart Data",
    lineTension: 0,           
    data: someData,
  }]
};
```